# derangements and permutations in cryptography

Tags: math, cryptography, combinatorics

i have a problem that i am having a bit of trouble with;

we are given a partial key (missing 11 letters) for a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher and asked to calculate the number of possible keys given that no plaintext letter can be mapped to itself.

ordinarily, the number of possible keys would be the number of derangements of the missing letters (!11), however 5 of the plaintext letters that are missing mappings already exist as mappings in the partial key, so logically it shouldnt matter what the mapping of those plaintext letters is, because they can never map to themselves.

so shouldnt the number of possible keys be 5! * !6, ie. (the number of permutations of the 5 already mapped free letters) * (the number of derangements of the remaining 6)?

the problem is that 5! * !6 = 31800 which is much less than !11 = 14684570

intuitively the set of derangements should be a smaller subset of !11, shouldnt it?

am i just getting something wrong in my arithmetic? or am i completely missing the concepts? any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks gus

ps. i know this isn't strictly a programming question, but it is a computing question and related to a programming project, so i thought it might be pertinent. also, i posted it on math.stackexchange.com yesterday but havent had any responses yet..

EDIT: corrected the value of !11

Comment: Another plausible destination for this question would be http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ (although check their help section to be sure).

Comment: Just two short comments before I post a complete answer: !11 is not 39916800, and 5!*6! is just a subset of the proper result, as the two groups can be also 'mixed together', not just permutated independently.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, 11! = 39916800, !11 = 14684570 - i will amend it.. how would you express the two groups as 'mixed together'? i think that is the part that i am not quite getting.. thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem can be rephrased as the following:

How many permutation has a list with elements `a_0, a_1, ... a_n-1, b_0, b_1, ..., b_m-1`, in which no `a_k` element is at position `k`? (Let us denote this number with `p_{n,m}` - your specific question is the value of `p_{6,5}`.)

Please note that your suggested formula 5!*!6 is not correct because of the following:
it only counts the cases, where the `a_k`s are in the first 6 positions (without any of them being in the position of its own index), and the `b_k`s on the last 5.
You do not count any other configurations like: `a_3, b_4, b_1, a_0, a_5, b_0, a_2, b_2, b_3, a_1, a_4`, where the order is totally mixed.

Your other idea about the result being a subset of the !11-element derangement on all the elements is also not correct, as any of the `b_k`s can be at any position.

However, we can easily add a recursive formula for `p_{n,m}` by separating it into two cases based on the position of `a_0`.

1. If `a_0` gets in one of the positions `1, 2, ..., n-1`. (`n-1` different possibilities.)
   This means that neither `a_0` is at position `0`, and it also prevents another `a_k` from being at position `k` by occupying that position. Thus this `a_k` becomes 'free', it can go to any other positions. If `a_0` gets fixed this way, the other elements can be permutated in `p_{n-2,m+1}` different ways.
2. If `a_0` gets in one of the positions `n, n+1, ..., n+m-1`. (`m` different possibilities.)
   This way no other `a_k` gets prevented to be at the position corresponding to it's index. The other elements can be permutated in `p_{n-1,m}` different ways.

Adding this together gives the recursion: `p_{n,m} = (n-1)*p_{n-2,m+1} + m*p_{n-1,m}`. The halting conditions are `p_{0,m}=m!` for every `m`, as it means, that each element can be at any location.

I also coded it in python:

```
import math

def derange(n,m):
    if n<0:
        return 0
    elif n==0:
        return math.factorial(m)
    else:
        return (n-1)*derange(n-2, m+1) + m*derange(n-1, m)

print derange(6,5)
```

gives 22852200.

If you are interested in the general case, you can find some related sequences on OEIS.
The search term 'differences of factorial numbers' can be interesting, e.g. in triangular form: http://oeis.org/A047920.
There is also an article mentioned there: http://www.pmfbl.org/janjic/enumfun.pdf, maybe it can help if you are interested in a generic closed formula for `n` and `m`.
Suddenly I didn't have any good idea to come up with, but I think this can be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks, it didnt really occur to me that i would need to find a recurrence relation, but it makes sense now. thanks for your help!